# Is there a way to consitently get inside the hidden room in Laying the Foundation?

Tags: antichamber

Slight spoiler alert!

The pillar in the middle of Laying the Foundation room is actually a path to a semi-secret room with... a formula.

[image: Laying the Foundation]

I've been to that room a number of times, but I cannot get there... consistently. When I WANT to get inside, it seems the small flying balls just don't open up the wall in a way to allow entry, making me run like a maniac for quite some time before, finally, a passage presents itself... then I usually botch the jump, it closes and I start the whole darn thing over.

Is there a sure-fire, consistent way to get inside that pillar?

Comment: Since the ball movement is mostly random, not really.

Comment: [Duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/103781/3921).

Comment: You can place a cube on the wall that got holes. Then you can drag that cube and there a ways you can drag it that actually the wall material will move. That way you can move the wall out of place step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's rather quite tricky to get it down, but the way I did it was...
>
> Don't keep moving once you've already broken a lot of the cube. **Let it
>   regenerate, and try again.** If you keep moving, it'll regenerate too
>   much over any area you want to move through.
>
> **I found that only one of the sides consistently made a hole big enough
>   to jump through.** Move around, try to look for the hole, wait for the
>   cube to regenerate, then move to where you saw the biggest hole. Then
>   move around to break it open again, and usually it breaks open in a
>   similar pattern as before.

Reference: [NeoGAF](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showpost.php?p=47205166&postcount=162).

> **One of the walls will regen slower than the others.** Thats your best bet for getting in.

Reference: [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/656678-antichamber/65355532).

Comment: I've checked and can confirm this works. One of the walls (the one towards the "exit door") regenerates at a lot slower pace than the others.

Thanks!